# C cedilla vs C acute accent with US international keyboard

Tags: keyboard, diacritics, non-ascii-characters, typography

Using a US qwerty keyboard (apple keyboard with numpad) and a US international layout, I'm trying to produce a c cedilla character (ç) using the (') + (c) method but it produces a (ć) instead. I tried using the compose key but it produce similar results.

I used to be able to produce the c cedilla, I must have changed something inadvertently. Any clue how to revert back the behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

Just found the easiest way to have Brazillian Portuguese C cedilla instead of C acute (and all other compositions). Works at least on arch, manjaro and ubuntu, with XFCE, KDE or Gnome:

`cp /usr/share/X11/locale/pt_BR.UTF-8/Compose ~/.XCompose`

Then logout and log back in